# Redshift pattern-matching

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

What will be matched if I have these condition on redshift select:

```
WHEN a.ref LIKE '%first_test%' 
    THEN 'FIRST'
WHEN a.ref LIKE '%first_test_abc_%'
    THEN 'SECOND'
WHEN a.ref LIKE '%first_test_abc_def%'
    THEN 'THIRD'
```

and I have a record which value in the column a.ref = 'abc_first_test_abc_def'? This record matches all three possibilities. It could be set to 'FIRST' or 'SECOND' or 'THIRD', as '%first_test%'  and also '%first_test_abc_%' match the pattern. Not just '%first_test_abc_def%'... Is this then done randomly? Or depending on the order I set the conditions?

Comment: Depending on the order you set the conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything that matches any will be `'FIRST'`.  `CASE` expressions are evaluated *in order*.  Anything that matches `'%first_test_abc_def%'` will also match `'%first_test%'`.

So, put the most restrictive first:

```
WHEN a.ref LIKE '%first_test_abc_def%'
    THEN 'THIRD'
WHEN a.ref LIKE '%first_test_abc_%'
    THEN 'SECOND'
WHEN a.ref LIKE '%first_test%' 
    THEN 'FIRST'
```

Note that this behavior is not specific to Redshift.  It is how SQL works.

Also, `_` is a wildcard for `LIKE`, so `'firstXtest'` would also match `'FIRST'`.